# A way to get full string?

Tags: javascript, string, substr

"UserInput" is what the user enters

The user will say Hello ***_*__*_*__*_***

For example here: We will use Hello World

```
    var input = UserInput;
    // Let's say the user inputs hello world
    if(input == "hello") {
      var cut = input.substr(6)
      console.log(cut)
    }
```

The user is inputting "hello world" but the if statement will not pick that up

my goal is to get the users input from an if statement, but have it so I can substr part of what they are saying

Comment: Use input.toLowerCase() == "hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.indexOf` to see if a string contains another string

```
var input = UserInput;
// Let's say the user inputs hello world
if ( input.indexOf( "hello" ) != -1 ) {
    var cut = input.substr(6)
    console.log(cut)
}
```

note that used this way it's case sensitive

Comment: what if say "world hello"

Comment: @Peter - It would still be the same, the string contains "hello" ?

Comment: "hello world" => "world", "hello world" => "hello"

Comment: @Peter - I have no idea what that is supposed to mean ?

Comment: hahaha sorry i was going to say "hello world" will give him "world", "world hello" will give him "hello". afaik he wants to get "substr part of what they are saying"

Comment: If the point is to only match strings that starts with "hello", the OP should specify that, and it would be as simple as `if ( input.indexOf( "hello" ) === 0 ) {`

Comment: i talk about `ar cut = input.substr(6)` part

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the input as well... fun with strings and arrays

```
//Lets say you have this string...
var input = "Hello world let me go back to bed"

//Split into an array
var eachWord = input.split(" ") //["Hello", "world", "let".....]

//Get first word
var firstWord = input[0];//"Hello"

//Get rest of sentence
var theRest = input.splice(1, input.length); //["world", "let", "me"...]

//put this into a string
theRest = theRest.join(" ") //"world let me...."
```

Now you can do whatever you like.  Also, it's important to make the string either lowercase or uppercase when you check against it

```
(firstWord.toLowerCase === "hello")
```